# Creating a jenkins job via the api throws an IOException

Tags: jenkins

I am running Jenkins ver. 2.7.1 on a windows server and I am attempting to create a new job via the api.

For simplicity I have turned off 'Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits' and am using PostMan to submit my request.

I am posting to `http://JENKINSSERVER/createItem?name=apicreateExample` with content type of `application/xml` and with the body of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<project>
    <description>BUILD # Telecoms1</description>
    <keepDependencies>true</keepDependencies>
    <properties/>
    <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
    <canRoam>true</canRoam>
    <disabled>true</disabled>
    <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
    <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
    <triggers/>
    <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
    <builders/>
    <publishers/>
    <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

However this call returns a 500 Server Error with a message starting `java.io.IOException: Unable to delete 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\apicreateExample'. Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.`

I have searched stackoverflow and google but haven't found references to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be fixed by changing my xml to start with `<?xml version="1.0"?>` not `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`. (My XML was generated by c#'s XmlWriter and this was produced by WriteStartDocument())

I don't know why this tripped up Jenkins, but hopefully this will help someone else who is encountering the same problem.